# Layout folder missing in new android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Why in recent SDK (v.22) there are no auto generated xml layout folder  when creating new project. And how to make that folder?

[image]

My pallete for layout is work, and when I import some of project that created using older SDK, that pallete still  appear. But what I didn't understand, why when I creating new project, there is no  layout folder and xml  file for layouts. When I was watching some video tutorial for beginner about android project, the xml layout and layout folder (under res folder) have  been auto generated.

Comment: "But what I didn't understand, why when I creating new project, there is no layout folder and xml file for layouts" -- did you check the "Create activity" checkbox in the new-project wizard?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, I check it.

Comment: @CommonsWare , pisang_ijo here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too, as many tutorials tell you to place things like Widget information, or preferences in that folder.  I just right clicked in the RES folder and added it myself.  Seems to work just fine.
When you reference whatever you have in your code, use "XML/whatever", rather than "/layout/whatever".